# How to check if a session created with @SessionAttributes exists (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session

Take a look at this code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
@SessionAttributes("address")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String welcome(Model model) {        
            Address address = new Address();            
            model.addAttribute("address", address);         
            return "welcome";           
    }   

}
```

Every time I reach the url "**/home**" the **welcome()** method is called, a new object **Address** is created, added to the model and saved inside the **session** with name **address**.

What's the best way to check if the **session "address"** already exists, in order to avoid the exection of this lines of code?

```
  Address address = new Address();          
  model.addAttribute("address", address);
```

I use this method, but I suppose there's a better and specific way to do it using **Spring features**.

```
@RequestMapping
public String welcome(Model model, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
   Address vecchioAddress = (Address)httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("address");
   if(vecchioAddress == null) {
            Address address = new Address();                
            model.addAttribute("address", address);
   }
```

}

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use [@SessionAttribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttribute.html) annotation to retrieve the existing attribute from session.

```
@RequestMapping
public String welcome(@SessionAttribute("address") Address address) {
  // something....
}
```

Comment: What if that session doesn't exist yet? Is there a way to prevent that method to return the error: HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request?

Comment: I think you should check it. maybe like this `if(!model.containsAttribute("address")){...}`

Answer (score 1):

You can make the use of `@SessionAttribute`.

```
public String welcome(Model model, @SessionAttribute("address") Address addres) { 
       if(address == null){
            Address address = new Address();            
            model.addAttribute("address", address); 

        }
        return "welcome";
}
```

Comment: What if that session doesn't exist yet? Is there a way to prevent that method to return the error: HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request?